# How do I tag an entire row in a table so that when I do a summary report the who row will appear?

Tags: microsoft-onenote, microsoft-onenote-2010

I have a table and I want to use tags to sort entire rows of entries, so that I can create a summary page which shows entire rows rather than individual entries. If I tag a single table entry, then just that cell appears in the summary report. If I highlight the whole row and tag, it tags each cell separately and they appear separately in the summary report. I want the rows to appear in the summary sheet as they appear in the master document.

Suggestions would be appreciated.